# Spark withColumn working for modifying column but not adding a new one

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Scala 2.12 and Spark 2.2.1 here. I have the following code:

```
myDf.show(5)
myDf.withColumn("rank", myDf("rank") * 10)
myDf.withColumn("lastRanOn", current_date())
println("And now:")
myDf.show(5)
```

When I run this, in the logs I see:

```
+---------+-----------+----+
|fizz|buzz|rizzrankrid|rank|
+---------+-----------+----+
|   2|   5| 1440370637| 128|
|   2|   5| 2114144780|1352|
|   2|   8|  199559784|3233|
|   2|   5| 1522258372| 895|
|   2|   9|  918480276| 882|
+---------+-----------+----+
And now:
+---------+-----------+-----+
|fizz|buzz|rizzrankrid| rank|
+---------+-----------+-----+
|   2|   5| 1440370637| 1280|
|   2|   5| 2114144780|13520|
|   2|   8|  199559784|32330|
|   2|   5| 1522258372| 8950|
|   2|   9|  918480276| 8820|
+---------+-----------+-----+
```

So, interesting:

- The first `withColumn` works, transforming each row's `rank` value by multiplying itself by 10
- However the second `withColumn` fails, which is just adding the current date/time to all rows as a new `lastRanOn` column

**What do I need to do to get the `lastRanOn` column addition working?**

Comment: Why the DV? Its not a duplicate, it shows research & effort, is on topic and contains an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)...

Comment: Why are you using Scala 2.12 with Spark. Some features might not work as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example is probably too simple, because modifying `rank` should also not work.

`withColumn` does not update DataFrame, it's create a new DataFrame.

So you must do:

```
// if myDf is a var
myDf.show(5)
myDf = myDf.withColumn("rank", myDf("rank") * 10)
myDf = myDf.withColumn("lastRanOn", current_date())
println("And now:")
myDf.show(5)
```

or for example:

```
myDf.withColumn("rank", myDf("rank") * 10).withColumn("lastRanOn", current_date()).show(5)
```

Only then you will have new column added - after reassigning new DataFrame reference

Comment: Add one more comment: Just remember DataFrame/Dataset is immutable as RDD.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign it after updating like this :

```
myDf=myDf.withColumn("rank", myDf("rank") * 10)
myDf=myDf.withColumn("lastRanOn", current_date()
```